# How do I loop the queue of sounds in AVQueuePlayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, avqueueplayer

I know multiple questions concerning the same issue exist, but after following [this one's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890087/repeat-avplayeritem-in-avqueueplayer) suggestions, I run into a couple of problems.

I have everything set up but I get to mach errors everytime I use kMTTimeZero.

```
soundQueue = [AVQueuePlayer queuePlayerWithItems:soundEmotions];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:[soundEmotions lastObject]];
```

Here's what I've done .

```
- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Do stuff here
    NSLog(@"End has been reached.");

    // Set it back to the beginning
    [soundQueue seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];

    //Replay
    [soundQueue play];

}
```

> ERROR: Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:   "_kCMTimeZero",
>   referenced from:
>         -[ViewController playerItemDidReachEnd:] in ViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`kCMTimeZero` is a symbol in the *CoreMedia.framework*, therefore you have to add this framework to the "Link Binary With Libraries" section in the "Build Phases" of your target.

Comment: Thank you! I added the framework and it builds just fine, but for some reason it still doesn't loop the sound. Am I not doing it correctly? Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out!. Thank you though!

Comment: @KingPolygon, what did you do to make the AVQueuePlayer loop?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this approach to **observe last item** and then `seek to kCMTimeZero`

```
 override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

        if keyPath == "currentItem" {

            print("Next Track...", currentTrackIndex)

            if currentTrackIndex > 0 {
                self.isPlaying = true
            }

            currentTrackIndex += 1
            if currentTrackIndex > playerQueue.items().count {
                currentTrackIndex = 0
                playerQueue.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
            }
        }
    }
```

And then

```
private func observeTrackChanged(of player : AVQueuePlayer) {

        player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem", options: .new, context: nil)
    }
```